# Iteration over two object's keys to set one objects property to the value of the other Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to iterate over two objects and set only some of the properties from one to the values of another.

The objects are of type `Outlet`

These are the keys I was looking to copy from one to the other (there are more but for simplicity here they are)

```
const oldOutlet = new getOutletFromId(Id);
const newOutlet = new Outlet();

const keys: (keyof Outlet)[] = [
      "version",
      "isHidden",
      "groupId",
      "salesAreaId",
      "salesCodeId",
    ];

 keys.forEach((key) => {
        newOutlet[key] = oldOutlet[key];
      }
    });
```

But I then get an error for

```
Type 'string | number | boolean | Guid | ... more ... | null' is not assignable to type 'never'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

I know I could set each of the properties individually, but I am interested in how to apply this to a general and still assuring some type safety in the loop

Comment: Shouldn't this be a method on `Outlet`? I don't see much value of keeping this copy functionality outside of it. Also, the loop is a bit of an overkill. Just list all the property copies: `newOutlet.version = oldOutlet.version` etc. You end up with about the same amount of lines but without having to do type acrobatics to make all of this type safe or to bypass the type checks.

Comment: What's `Outlet`?  Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground(link)](https://tsplay.dev/Nd4onN), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: Everything works as expected and without errors. Please, add a good example. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyCuAXEBTR0DeAoavrAHsA7CRAJ3mEQLOgAoc8AHeAIxAEthoA3FMiB2IB+AFzRSZDkQDmAGka4W7LtA4QAEhwAm2lETETy0+YujLO3GWQLwmASW2HJJhXnNtLEsKggBBMhQwR2djWTdmT1UIHxQIAGECPRDxF3CzAEpMAF8sXKxCEnQCEG0EZDRoAF5MM2tbB21xAHIARmaI3HUtXX0WgCYOsxjfAKDHFoBmIfcRuMTkpuhmgBYZvD4BISIWgFZmvOhIOCRURABuAuJSaCIUAHdys+rbh5OKxDoMy6ui6ABrFAATwg4jogKBBAAZu8zhkANoAXRe8LMACJNoJiGjOtA0d0dHoiDj0fU7I4Se40XN-IFgtpKXhqbEEkkUBSFIifhCIAA6KE0ACiYGAAAs6ODgVkqgA+WruO6PU5oeEQ5E1EplZWIVXArl5b5YX4QEooXkgAgyOiKp5oDJAA

Comment: Here is an example of the error [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIFcwBsJmQbwChkSSA3aAZ2AHsQAuZSsKUAcwG5jTlhKAJYABMhEBkxbsuPZGyg10ABwCSQxiHQBbAEbRpPSnByUAglAhxVjZqxCdupQ8YDCNUVYm37AX0KEEdMzIIBAA7hjYuMgAvAQOsvJKHgCMADTxfIIiYowA5ABMuekGRhCm5pZqyLkAzEXxTmWu7lW5ACz1PBRQ1HR5AKy5hN7IcJRomDhgXP6BeDRYQhFTMXE8cgoqVckADMWkmcKi4gU7nY6l5RYetWf7JI2UzRA3bXfx3b0n-WfDo+PLXAzAIgIIAawgAE9KIwABQQyE0GATSJgACUAG0ALqrDHxABEn1oIHx92Q+MO2RJZPxGySQlJhCxMwRlAAdDAaFAAKKIAAWsPhULRMQAfGtSCFwpNcBiETjYgsljKwHKoczhmjgYEFhA2VgaGxYVLAeigA)